# How to make list from .ods file?

Tags: python, list, ods

I want to make a `2-D list` from `.ods` file after reading this file. From following code I have gotten following output.

```
from pyexcel_ods import get_data
data = get_data("demo.ods")
```

> Output:

```
In [2]: data
Out[2]: 
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',
              [['ID',
                'Start_1',
                'End_1',
                'Start_2',
                'End_2',
                'Start_3',
                'End_3'],
               [1007, 59, 93, 160, 194, 424, 459],
               [1011, 436, 460, 154, 180, 500, 527],
               [1025, 459, 501, 304, 334, 3, 32]])])
```

But I want output like `my_2d_list`.

```
my_2d_list = [[1007, 59, 93, 160, 194, 424, 459],
               [1011, 436, 460, 154, 180, 500, 527],
               [1025, 459, 501, 304, 334, 3, 32]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to remove the "sheet name" and "column header"

```
# You can add below code:

od = OrderedDict([('Sheet1',
              [['ID',
                'Start_1',
                'End_1',
                'Start_2',
                'End_2',
                'Start_3',
                'End_3'],
               [1007, 59, 93, 160, 194, 424, 459],
               [1011, 436, 460, 154, 180, 500, 527],
               [1025, 459, 501, 304, 334, 3, 32]])])

my_2d_list = list(od.values())[0][1:]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help! :)